# Distance Metric in 4 dimensions $\Bbb R^3\times SO(2)$

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, metric-spaces

The euclidean distance metric, $\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2+dz^2}$, shows the shortest distance between two points in $\Bbb R^3$.  What would be the distance metric to show the shortest distance between two points in  $\Bbb R^3\times SO(2)$?

The applications for this would be used to plan a path througha graph with nodes with 4 degrees of freedom $[x,y,z,r_z]$.
Where the translation in $\Bbb R^3$ is
$$
\mathbf{T}=
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Where the rotation in $SO(2)$ is
$$
\mathbf{R}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(r_z) & -\sin(r_z)\\
\sin(r_z) & \cos(r_z)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Combining these into a homogenous transform we get
$$
\mathbf{H} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(r_z) & -\sin(r_z) & 0 & x\\
\sin(r_z) & \cos(r_z) & 0 & y\\
0 & 0 & 1 & z\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Algorithms such as A* assign a cost to each node based on the traveled distance from the start and the estimated distance to the goal.  I'm not sure how to do this when a single rotation is added to the normal 3D points.

This metric would obviously have to satisfy the triangle inequality.

EDIT:

For example.
$$
\text{node }a = [1,0,0,0]\\
\text{node }b = [3,0,0,0]\\
\text{node }c = [2,0,0,\pi]\\
$$
I need a distance metric s.t. $d(a,c)\le d(a,b)+d(b,c)$.

Using this distance metric which node is closer to $a$?

Comment: It seems that you want neither SO(1) nor SO(3) but SO(2). In addition, it is unclear which metric on the product space you are using. Is it product Riemannian metric?

Comment: If this is indeed the product Riemannian metric then the solution is very simple.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't the Riemennian metric between two 4D nodes with $[x,y,z,rz]$ be just the inner product of the two vectors?  I don't think that satisfies the triangle inequality.  I'll try to think of an example to put in the question.

Comment: This is all very confusing.  An element of $\mathbb{R}^3\times SO(3)$ can't be represented as a $4$-vector $[x,y,z,rz]$ of real numbers, since $\mathbb{R}^3\times SO(3)$ is a six-dimensional space.  However, you talk about $rz$ as though it is a rotation.  Is $rz$ supposed to signify a rotation in three dimensions?  Such a rotation cannot be represented by a single number.

Comment: I think studiosus may be right that I should have used $SO(2) $ instead of $SO(3)$.

Comment: @joshkarges If that's the case, then this is going to have more than four dimensions for sure...

Comment: I think $rz$ is supposed to be a symbol for an element of $SO(2)<SO(3)$ representing a rotation about z-axis.

Comment: I'll clarify rz in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will view the space you are interested in as the product $M=R^3\times S^1$, where $S^1=SO(2)$. Both factors in this space have natural Riemannian metric, therefore, I will equip their product with the product Riemannian metric. Let $d$ denote the distance function on $M$ determined by the Riemannian metric. Observe that the Riemannian metric on $M$ is flat and complete; the universal cover of $M$ (with the lifted Riemannian metric) is isometric to the Euclidean 4-space $R^4$. Therefore, the distance $d(p,q)$ between points $p, q\in M$, is given by
$$
\min_{n} d(\tilde p, \tilde q_n),
$$ 
where $\tilde p$ is a fixed lift of $p$ to $R^4$ and $\tilde q_n$ are lifts of $q$ to $R^4$. Concretely, we can compute this quantity as follows. I will use the coordinates $p=(P, arg(p))$ on $M$, where $P$ belongs to $R^3$ and $arg(p)\in [0,2\pi)$ denotes the argument of the projection of $p$ to $S^1$. 
Then
$$
d^2(p,q)=  |P-Q|^2 + \min \{(arg(p)-arg(q))^2, (arg(p)-arg(q)-2\pi)^2\}. 
$$

Comment: I think this is on the right track, and I'd upvote you if I had the reputation.  The only thing I might add, is that since we're mapping the $\Bbb R^3\times S^1$ space into $\Bbb R^4$ space, there is a user choice scaling constant to move from $S^1$ to $\Bbb R$.  This is analogous to mapping an angle to an arc length of a circle.  They're proportional by the radius of the circle.  For my application this scaling constant could be the radius of the footprint of my robot, or it could be related to the inertia of the robot.  Just some ideas.

Comment: @joshkaeges: If you change the metric in the circle to depend on the point in the 3d space then things will get much more complicated as the metric will no longer be flat (it then will be called "warped product metric". Then I am not sure what the answer is.